# Constantly update function's parameters

Tags: java, android, function, seekbar

I need some help adjusting a function to be constantly updating (<- that may not make sense at first but hopefully a little more explanation will make it clear).  **This is going to be a long post but please bear with me.**

I've got an **Activity** and a **Custom Class**.  The **Activity's** Java file only contains a reference to the `seekbar` that's in it and the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`.  The XML contains said seekbar, and a reference? to the **Custom Class** (not sure if it's actually called a reference).  Here's the code for both:

Java:

```
public class Painting extends Activity
{
    static SeekBar curveBar;
    SampleView sampleView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_painting);

        curveBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.curveBar);
        sampleView = new SampleView(this);

        curveBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress >= 50
                {
                    sampleView.updatePath(progress);
                }
                else if (progress < 50)
                {
                    sampleView.updatePath((-1) * progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(Painting.this, "Value: " + curveBar.getProgress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    tools:context="com.example.android.postvu.SampleView">

    <com.example.android.postvu.SampleView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/curveBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

My **Custom Class** is what actually draws the canvas with the curve on the top half.  In this class I've got 2 constructors:

```
public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setTextSize(90);
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        mPath = new Path();
        makePath(mPath);

        mPathPaint = new Paint();
        mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    public SampleView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setTextSize(90);
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        Log.d("LOGCAT", "" + value);

        mPath = new Path();
        makePath(mPath);

        mPathPaint = new Paint();
        mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  }
```

**AND FINALLY** the 2 functions that I'm stuck on.  The first is simply being called from the `seekbar` in the **Activity** and it's just so that I can get the value of the seekbar at all times while it's being moved.

```
public void updatePath(int seekbarProgress)
{
    value = seekbarProgress * 6;
}
```

The second function is what draws the curve itself based on a Bezier Curve:

```
public void makePath(Path p)
    {
//            p.moveTo(250, -300);
        p.moveTo(0,0);
//            p.cubicTo(-250, -550, 750, -550, 250, -300);

            p.cubicTo(0,-400,600,-400,600,0); //semi-circle?
//            p.cubicTo(-600, -400, 600, -400, 0, 0); //as far as the curve probably should allow
//        p.cubicTo(0, 0, 0, 0, 620,0); //flat line
    }
```

**MY ACTUAL QUESTION**

How can I change the `makePath` function to take the value variable from the `updatePath` function so that I can make the `p.cubicTo` look like `p.cubicTo(0,-400,600,-400,value,0)` considering that I'm calling `makePath` in both of the constructors?

## ****EDIT****

The 2 constructors from my **Custom Class** (and relevant function) now look like this:

```
public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(true);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setTextSize(90);
    mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

    mPath = new Path();
//  updatePath(value);
    makePath(mPath, value);

    mPathPaint = new Paint();
    mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}


public SampleView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setTextSize(90);
    mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

    mPath = new Path();
//  updatePath(value);
    makePath(mPath, value);
    Log.d("LOGTAG2", "" + value);

    mPathPaint = new Paint();
    mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

public int updatePath(int seekbarProgress)
{
    return value = seekbarProgress * 6;
}

public void makePath(Path p, int number)
{
    p.moveTo(0,0);
    p.cubicTo(0, 0, 0, 0, number,0); //flat line
}
```

Android Studio is highlighting `updatePath` and when I hover over it, it tells me `Return value of the method is never used`.  Unless I'm doing something wrong, I **am** using that value in **both** constructors where it says `makePath(mPath, value);`.  I'm not sure what else to do at this point because it doesn't make any sense to me.  I really want to know 1) how to fix it and 2) what's causing it (why it's telling me that I am not using it (which I think I am)).

Comment: So you want to [overload the makePath function](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/)?

Comment: Or do you want to just change `makePath( Path)` to `makePath( Path, int)`, and pass a constant for the second parameter in the constructor calls?

Comment: @AndyThomas I apologize for the very late reply, I became incredibly busy with other things.  that's basically what i want to do, but instead of the `int` being a constant, i want it to be the `value` that is calculated in the `updatePath` function.  i'm not sure if this is possible but i'm hoping it is.

Comment: @MarcKaram - You can either `return value;` from the `public ***int*** updatePath( ... )` method -- or store the value as a member. By the way, consider giving  `value` a more specific name.

Comment: @AndyThomas I tried what you said & changed the `updatePath` function to an `int` return type & added `return value;` at the end. I also changed the `makePath` function to `public void makePath(Path p, int number)` & within the function i put `number` in the `p.cubicTo` method. I then changed the `makePath` calls in the constructors to `makePath(mPath, value)`.  It all compiles but now it's giving me a warning saying that on the `updatePath` function, the `Return value of the method is never used`.  Did I do something wrong? When I run it, no text appears on screen, just a seekbar.

Comment: Unused code is frequently an indication of error. Hence the warning. This particular warning sounds like it's telling you that yes, you have returned the value, but in none of the callers are you using that value. In a caller, you could say `int newValue = updatePath( ... );`. That will lead to an unused variable warning, unless you use `newValue` in some way.

Comment: @AndyThomas I really appreciate your help with this.  If you could please, I've added to an **EDIT** section at the bottom of the post the code so that it's clear exactly what the code is, VS. trying to type it in here.  If you could **PLEASE** help me (as I said above) 1) figure out how to fix it and 2) understand what's causing it (why it's telling me that it's not being used